# Unable to update element ID of HTML text using Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Using JS and AJAX, I am loading a template file on my Index.html page.
Once the template is loaded, I then want to apply changes to the DOM.

- The template is successfully loading on the index.html page.
- The JS is FAILING to update the DOM elements.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have 2 html pages.

1. index.html
2. page-banner-area.html

index.html

```
<div id="page-banner-area"></div> 

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#page-banner-area").load("assets/static_html/page-banner-area.html");
    $("#title").text('Join a Community Group in your area.');
    $("#keypoint-1").text('We are against mandatory vaccines &amp; passports.');
    $("#keypoint-2").text('We do not stand for corruption &amp; censorship.');
    $("#keypoint-3").text('We believe in freedom!');
});
</script>
```

page-banner-area.html

```
<div class="p-2 flex-grow-1">
   <h3><span id="title"></span></h3>
      <span id="keypoint-1"></span><br />
      <span id="keypoint-2"></span><br />
      <span id="keypoint-3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're executing your `text()` functions before you know that `load()` has actually finished loading your html page. They should be in the callback for `load()`. See the docs for examples https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `load()` method is asynchronous, you need to do your changes within a callback method in order for them to be properly applied. See the JQuery docs for more information https://api.jquery.com/load/

As for a solution, you should be doing this instead:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#page-banner-area").load("assets/static_html/page-banner-area.html", function() {
    $("#title").text('Join a Community Group in your area.');
    $("#keypoint-1").text('We are against mandatory vaccines &amp; passports.');
    $("#keypoint-2").text('We do not stand for corruption &amp; censorship.');
    $("#keypoint-3").text('We believe in freedom!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this can solve your problem!

```html
<div id="page-banner-area"></div> 

<script>
$(() => {
  $("#page-banner-area")
    .load("assets/static_html/page-banner-area.html", () => {
      $("#title").text('Join a Community Group in your area.');
      $("#keypoint-1").text('We are against mandatory vaccines &amp; passports.');
      $("#keypoint-2").text('We do not stand for corruption &amp; censorship.');
      $("#keypoint-3").text('We believe in freedom!');
    });
});
</script>
```